# Misalignment between badge progress trackers in user profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, badge-progress

I think there's been a recent vertical misalignment between the left and right badge progress trackers on the activity tab of the user profile.

[image]

Using Firefox 94.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro.
rev 2021.11.22.40798

**Edit:**

Sebastian Simon contributed two screenshots in the comments, so unless I'm mistaken the badge was aligned with the bottom in both cases until a a few days ago.

[image: screenshot of alignment tracking bade]
[image: screenshot of alignment not tracking bade]

Comment: What is the issue? What do you think it should look like?

Comment: @SebastianSimon If you look at your own profile on MSE it doesn't have the  misalignment so compare it with the screenshot. See the difference?

Comment: It looks identical. Here’s a [screenshot](//i.stack.imgur.com/5cfkU.png) with the flex rows highlighted. Do you want it to look more like the [“track privilege” view](//i.stack.imgur.com/VZ65q.png)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon yes, unless I'm mistaken until a few days ago that's how the alignment was for both cases.

Comment: So things changed, probably because of making that page responsive. I don't see any true bug here. Does this make it less accessible?

Comment: @Luuklag does it make it look better, or consistent between the 2 cases? I'd say no, so it has all the usual traits of a misalignment bug.